# Javascript detect android native browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to detect with javascript the native android browser (the one that comes installed on every android phone).

What should I look for in useragent ?

Comment: One size doesn't fit all. Some Android phone pretends itself as iPhone with iPhone's user agent.

Comment: i don`t understand "feature detection" , can you please explain?

Comment: [googling javascript android user agent](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+android+user+agent) - 
[googling js feature detection](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+feature+detection)

Comment: Feature detection doesn't work for *every* situation. 

If you check the user agent string for /Android/i you will have some luck, but that doesn't say what version of webkit it is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work.

```
var nua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_android = ((nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 &&     nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1) && !(nua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1));
```

Comment: It seems it does not work for Android 4.4+ (they changed the native browser)

Answer (score 8):

Native browser, we could not detect at the first go itself, using the above mentioned code:

```
var nua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_android = ((nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 &&     nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1) && !(nua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1));
```

as for most devices we got the following as the user agent for chrome browser:
[image]

and in the native browser:

[image]

And carried out this observation for Samsung Galaxy S3, htc desire, Asus Zenfone5.

And found out that the "Chrome/30.0.0.0" or the "chrome/" along withthe version is present for most devces including Zenfone 5, Samsung Galaxy s3. But the "version/" no. present in the user agent object is more than enough to differentiate the native and the Chrome.

We used the following code:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_native_android = ((ua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && ua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 && ua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1) && (ua.indexOf('Version') > -1));
```

Hope, it's useful for you too... :)

Comment: Is this still applicable to the native browser of Android 5.1.1? Because I can get as far as `var is_native_android = ua.indexOf("android") > -1 && ua.indexOf("mobile") && ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1` but all the other identifiers seem to fail. It looks like the native browser is using AppleWebkit - Mozilla/5.0.

Comment: This seems to be working on old as well as newer Android stock browsers.

Comment: This won't work in Android 6.0.1 (at least not on my US T-mobile S6).  Native Browser is now based on Chrome and it's really tough to tell the difference.  The only difference I saw were manufacturer specific words (for me it said Samsung a couple times).   My friend's S7 doesn't even have the native browser anymore, well Chrome is now the native browser for that phone.  But the good thing is I guess it doesn't matter anymore since both _should_ be similar

Answer (score 3):

See [this page](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html) for an overview of different user agent strings.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're being downvoted, that's a good resource.

Answer (score -3):

Try something like this:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
  // Do something
}
```

or

check this url:
http://davidwalsh.name/detect-android

Comment: This will match Firefox on Android, too.

Comment: This detects the OS only - nothing to do with the question the user asked.